# SSRS Border at the end of a Multipage Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, border

I need to put a border at every page break in my Tablix. I searched everywhere but I didn't find an usable solution.

This is what I have now
[image: what i have]

I'm trying to put a border at the end of each page like that.
[image: what i need]

Comment: The screenshots seem quite useless. Please show the code producing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textbox in the footer of the report and set the border style for the top of it to solid and then set the border color.

[image]